org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400
I am trying to hit a GET API in my spring boot project but getting the above error. Below is the API code and the code through which I am hitting this API
    @RequestMapping(value = "/apiUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void apiMethodName(@RequestParam("restrictProfileDate") 
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime restrictProfileDate) {

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();       
LocalDate dateValue= LocalDate.now();
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("restrictProfileDate", dateValue.atStartOfDay());        
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(apiEndPoint, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(params, headers), String.class, params);


You should have and provide a more detail cause to your error

Switch your api parameter to String and log (or debug) your income

I'm not sure what your error is but maybe you can see more details if you log your response and headers. For debugging purposes you can set an Errorhandler for your RestTemplate like so:


        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                System.out.printf("Response Status: %s%n", response.getRawStatusCode());
                System.out.printf("Response Headers: %n%s%n", response.getHeaders());
                System.out.printf("Response Body: %n%s%n", new String(getResponseBody(response)));
                super.handleError(response);
            }
        });

`

